# How to make the call with Zebble for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I need to launch the phone dialer on ios, android, and windows phone platform with Zebble like below screenshot.

[Dial pad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygJuD.png)

I wrote some code to run dial pad but in Zebble, I could not access activity to start.

```
public async Task DialNumber()
{
    if(Device.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial,Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:111111"));
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make call with Zebble you can use this API

```
public async Task DialNumber()
{
    await Device.Messaging.PhoneCall("111111", null, OnError.Toast);
}
```

To read more about zebble API go to http://zebble.net/docs/device-messaging-make-a-phone-call-send-sms-or-email website.

Disclaimer: I am a Zebble project contributor and engage in technical support.